# Determing a blank value, best way to do this

Tags: php, methods

Currently whenever i am trying to determine when a variable is not defined i use the code

> if($variable=="")

however i have been told by people to use the function

> if(empty($variable))

Reading on this, it returns false if the value is 0, and i have plenty of array values that are zero that cant be returning false. i could always add ||$variable==0) to skip this.

But all i am asking is why is this a preferred method for determining empty variables, is it efficiency or is there more to it than that?

Comment: This all depends on your needs.  `isset()` and `empty()` are the primary methods used.

Comment: why are these methods preferred over a simple if statement of if($var=="") though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know, use strict type comparison:

```
if (empty($variable) && $variable !== 0) // !== instead of !=
```

Generally, you should use `isset()` - if the variable hasn't yet been defined, it returns false:

```
$a = 4;
echo isset($a) ? 'a' : 'no a'; // a
echo isset($b) ? 'b' : 'not to b'; // not to b
```

Comment: okay isset actually makes more sense for what I am asking, that still leaves me wondering, what is the actually reasoning that using isset or empty is advantageous to if($var=="") since that does result with code that runs properly

Comment: If the variable hasn't yet been set, then depending on how PHP is configured it may continue happily, or it may error out and stop. If it continues, it takes **significantly** longer to try and read from a variable that doesn't exist yet (read: not normally worth caring about). The main reason to use `isset()` is because it's the **right way** to check :P Oh, and the fatal error thing. That's quite a big deal too.

Comment: okay so its mainly efficiency, i've never received an error message from it and i have error messages on. Ill start switching my code to the proper use, thanks.